# Cannot run ndk-build on Terminal

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am new to using NDK platform and I get the following error on running ndk-build in the terminal:

```
aditya@aditya-Vostro1510:~/workspace/Fibonacci$ ~/android-ndk-r9/ndk-build 
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-18 
is larger than android:minSdkVersion8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: ./jni/Android.mk    
/home/aditya/android-ndk-r9/build/core/add-application.mk:176: *** Android NDK:      Aborting...    .  Stop.
```

I didnt make an application.mk file as I read it was optional and the video tutorial I refered did not include it too.
android.mk contains foll code:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_Native_fibonacci_fiblib.c
LOCAL_MODULE := com_Native_fibonacci_fiblib
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I tried searching for help on forums but failed.Please give me a detailed solution for this.

Comment: I believe android.mk and Android.mk are two different files on Linux systems.

Comment: Do the file names have the same capitalization? I.e. `Android.mk`, not `android.mk`

Comment: Thanks guys it worked.Glad you people helped